# Polymorphism Bank Application

Tags: java, polymorphism

Okay, so I'm Sorry there is so much code, i feel like all of this is could be shortened so much. Anyways, to my question, I want to add `changeStreet(), changeCity(), changeState(), changeZip()` methods to the customers class in order to change street etc.
I am having trouble understanding polymorphism and how any of my variables relate, it all seems very redundant.. can someone help me understand this topic and my code.

**Tester Class**:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Bank easySave = new Bank();
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    String action, acctID;
    Double amt;

    /* display menu of choices */
    do {    
        System.out.println("\nDeposit\\Withdrawal\\Check balance");
        System.out.println("Add an account\\Remove an account");
        System.out.println("Edit Account");
        System.out.println("Quit\n");
        System.out.print("Enter choice: ");
        action = input.next();

        if (action.equalsIgnoreCase("A")) {
            easySave.addAccount();

        } else if (!action.equalsIgnoreCase("Q")) {
            System.out.print("Enter account ID: ");
            acctID = input.next();

            if (action.equalsIgnoreCase("D")) {
                System.out.print("Enter deposit amount: ");
                amt = input.nextDouble();
                easySave.transaction(1, acctID, amt);

            } else if (action.equalsIgnoreCase("W")) {
                System.out.print("Enter withdrawal amount: ");
                amt = input.nextDouble();
                easySave.transaction(2, acctID, amt);

            } else if (action.equalsIgnoreCase("C")) {
                easySave.checkBalance(acctID);

            } else if (action.equalsIgnoreCase("R")) {
                easySave.deleteAccount(acctID);

            } else if (action.equalsIgnoreCase("E")) {
                System.out.println("Street(S)\\ State(ST) \\");
                System.out.println("City(C) \\ Zip(Z) \\");

                if (action.equalsIgnoreCase("S")){
                    easySave.changeStreet(Street);

                } else if (action.equalsIgnoreCase("ST")){
                    easySave.changeState(State);

                } else if (action.equalsIgnoreCase("C")){
                    easySave.changeCity(City);

                } else if (action.equalsIgnoreCase("Z")){
                    easySave.changeZip(Zip);        
                }
            } 
        }
    } while (!action.equalsIgnoreCase("Q"));
}
```

**Customer Class**:

```
private String firstName;
private String lastName;
private String Street;
private String State;
private String City;
private String Zip;


/**
 * constructor
 * pre: none
 * post: A Customer object has been created. 
 * Customer data has been initialized with parameters.
 */
public Customer(String fName, String lName, String s, String st, String c, String z) {
    firstName = fName;
    lastName = lName;
    Street = s;
    State = st;
    City = c;
    Zip = z;
}

public void changeStreet(String Street){
    Street = this.Street;
    System.out.println("yo");
}

public void changeState(String State){
    State = this.State;

}

public void changeCity(String City){
    City = this.City;

}

public void changeZip(String Zip){
    Zip = this.Zip;

}

/** 
 * Returns a String that represents the Customer object.
 * pre: none
 * post: A string representing the Customer object has 
 * been returned.
 */
public String toString() {
    String custString;

    custString = firstName + " " + lastName + "\n" 
                    + Street + "\n" + City + State + " \n" + Zip ;
    return(custString);
}
```

**Bank Class**:

```
private ArrayList<Account> accounts;
/**
 * constructor
 * pre: none
 * post: accounts has been initialized.
 */
public Bank() {
    accounts = new ArrayList<Account>();
}

/** 
 * Adds a new account to the bank accounts.
 * pre: none
 * post: An account has been added to the bank's accounts.
 */
public void addAccount() {
    Account newAcct;
    double bal;
    String fName, lName, s, st, c, z;
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    p("First name: ");
    fName = input.nextLine();
    p("Last name: ");
    lName = input.nextLine();
    p("Street");
    s = input.nextLine();
    p("State");
    st = input.nextLine();
    p("City");
    c = input.nextLine();
    p("Zip");
    z = input.nextLine();
    p("Beginning balance: ");
    bal = input.nextDouble();

    newAcct = new Account(bal, fName, lName, s, st, c, z);  //create acct object
    accounts.add(newAcct);                      //add account to bank accounts

    System.out.println("Account created. Account ID is: " + newAcct.getID());
}

/** 
 * Deletes an existing account.
 * pre: none
 * post: An existing account has been deleted.
 */
public void deleteAccount(String acctID) {
    int acctIndex;
    Account acctToMatch;

    acctToMatch = new Account(acctID);
    acctIndex = accounts.indexOf(acctToMatch);      //retrieve location of account
    if (acctIndex > -1) {
        accounts.remove(acctIndex);                 //remove account
        System.out.println("Account removed.");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Account does not exist.");
    }
}

/** 
 * Performs a transaction on an existing account. A transCode of 1 is for deposits 
 * and a transCode of 2 is for withdrawals.
 * pre: transCode is 1 or 2.
 * post: A transaction has occurred for an existing account.
 */
public void transaction(int transCode, String acctID, double amt) {
    int acctIndex;
    Account acctToMatch, acct;

    acctToMatch = new Account(acctID);
    acctIndex = accounts.indexOf(acctToMatch);      //retrieve location of account
    if (acctIndex > -1) {
        acct = accounts.get(acctIndex);             //retrieve object to modify
        if (transCode == 1) {
            acct.deposit(amt);
            accounts.set(acctIndex, acct);      //replace object with updated object
            System.out.println(acct);
        } else if (transCode == 2) {
            acct.withdrawal(amt);
            accounts.set(acctIndex, acct);      //replace object with updated object
            System.out.println(acct);
        }
    } else {
        System.out.println("Account does not exist.");
    }
}

/** 
 * Displays the account information, including the current balance, 
 * for an existing account.
 * pre: none
 * post: Account information, including balance, has been displayed.
 */
public void checkBalance(String acctID) {
    int acctIndex;
    Account acctToMatch, acct;

    acctToMatch = new Account(acctID);
    acctIndex = accounts.indexOf(acctToMatch);      //retrieve location of account
    if (acctIndex > -1) {
        acct = accounts.get(acctIndex); //retrieve object to display
        System.out.println(acct);
    } else {
        System.out.println("Account does not exist.");
    }
}
public static void p(String s) { System.out.println(s); }
```

**Account Class**:

```
private double balance;
private Customer cust;
private String acctID;

/**
 * constructor
 * pre: none
 * post: An account has been created. Balance and 
 * customer data has been initialized with parameters.
 */
public Account(double bal, String fName, String lName, String s, String st, String z, String c) {
    balance = bal;
    cust = new Customer(fName, lName, s ,st ,z ,c);
    acctID = fName.substring(0,1) + lName;
}

/**
 * constructor
 * pre: none
 * post: An empty account has been created with the specified account ID.
 */
public Account(String ID) {
    balance = 0;
    cust = new Customer("", "", "", "", "", "");
    acctID = ID;
}


/** 
 * Returns the account ID.
 * pre: none
 * post: The account ID has been returned.
 */
public String getID() {
    return(acctID);
}


/** 
 * Returns the current balance.
 * pre: none
 * post: The account balance has been returned.
 */
public double getBalance() {
    return(balance);
}

/** 
 * A deposit is made to the account.
 * pre: none
 * post: The balance has been increased by the amount of the deposit.
 */
public void deposit(double amt) {
    balance += amt;
}

/** 
 * A withdrawal is made from the account if there is enough money.
 * pre: none
 * post: The balance has been decreased by the amount withdrawn.
 */
public void withdrawal(double amt) {
    if (amt <= balance) {
        balance -= amt;
    } else {
        System.out.println("Not enough money in account.");
    }
}


/** 
 * Returns a true when objects have matching account ids.
 * pre: none
 * post: true has been returned when the objects are equal,
 * false returned otherwise.
 */
public boolean equals(Object acct) {
    Account testAcct = (Account)acct;
    if (acctID.equals(testAcct.acctID)) {
            return(true);
        } else {
            return(false);
        }
}

/** 
 * Returns a String that represents the Account object.
 * pre: none
 * post: A string representing the Account object has 
 * been returned.
 */
public String toString() {
    String accountString;
    NumberFormat money = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();

    accountString = acctID + "\n";
    accountString += cust.toString();
    accountString += "Current balance is " + money.format(balance);
    return(accountString);
}
```

I am getting **errors** in below code:

```
if (action.equalsIgnoreCase("S")){
    easySave.changeStreet(Street);

} else if (action.equalsIgnoreCase("ST")){
    easySave.changeState(State);

} else if (action.equalsIgnoreCase("C")){
    easySave.changeCity(City);

} else if (action.equalsIgnoreCase("Z")){
    easySave.changeZip(Zip);

}
```

Comment: You setters are backwards, instead of `Street = this.Street;` it should be `this.Street = Street;`

Comment: crap let me flip them, excuse me for the bad code its late at night and i barely understand the polymorphism thing

Comment: You might like to have a read through [Code Conventions for the Java TM Programming Language](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconvtoc-136057.html), it will make it easier for people to read your code and for you to read others

Comment: From what I can tell, you don't have any polymorphism. Polymorphism is a way for an object to "act" like another object, normally through inheritance. Lets say you had a `Bank` and a `Custom`, both which inherited from `Addressable` which specified the means by which the address should be retrieved and changed, then `Bank` and `Custom` could "act" as `Addressable`, that's polymorphism ... why do I feel a song coming on...?

Comment: haha thank you, I am really trying here

Comment: @MadProgrammer - What??? I know what polymorphism is, and yet I don't understand your explanation at all.

Comment: @DavidWallace Why What's wrong with it?  `ArrayList` can "act" as a `List` because it inherits from `List`...

Comment: The reason you're having issues with the `if (action.equalsIgnoreCase("S")) { easySave.changeStreet(Street);` statements is because the variables `Street`, `State`, `City` and `Zip` are undefined within the scope that you are trying to use them...

Comment: "a way for an object to act like another object" - `Addressable` isn't an object in your example.  If you have an object like `bigUglyBank` - it's both an `Addressable` and a `Bank`; but there's only one object.  I prefer to think of it as a way to spread the definition of the behaviour of an object across more than one class.  It's got nothing to do with an object acting like something it's not.

Comment: yes atm I am trying to define them

Comment: so what your saying is that its variables acting as a part of that object ?

Comment: @DavidWallace But `Addressable` is a common ancestor from which both `Bank` and `Customer` inherit from.  You can then use both `Bank` and `Customer` where `Addressable` is expected, so they "act" like `Addressable` - it's overly simplified, but it's the best description I can come up with. "Male" and "Female" are both "Human", so either can be used where "Human" is acceptable, but don't send a "Male" to the "Female" bathroom :P

Comment: Umm, Brett, best to forget about the polymorphism.  MadProgrammer and I are having our own little battle here which is nothing to do with your question.  I think we both agree that polymorphism does not play any part in your program, so the whole discussion of what it is is kind of irrelevant.

Comment: @DavidWallace Hahahah :)

Comment: @DavidWallace And I'm using "act" very loosely here, "behave" might be a better description

Comment: @BrettCox Take a look at [Polymorphism](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/polymorphism.html) for more details

Comment: @MadProgrammer Sure, but asking a "Male" to act like a "Human" shouldn't require him to act like something he's not.  Unless, of course, you mean a male gorilla.

Comment: @DavidWallace Agreed, hence the comment *"normally through inheritance"* (in Java AFAIK, this is the only way)

Answer (score 0):

This probably won't answer the question, but will give you an idea of what polymorphism is...

Let's start with a basic concept of some kind of "address"

```
public class Address {

    private String street;
    private String state;
    private String city;
    private String zip;

    public String getStreet() {
        return street;
    }

    public void setStreet(String street) {
        this.street = street;
    }

    public String getState() {
        return state;
    }

    public void setState(String state) {
        this.state = state;
    }

    public String getCity() {
        return city;
    }

    public void setCity(String city) {
        this.city = city;
    }

    public String getZip() {
        return zip;
    }

    public void setZip(String zip) {
        this.zip = zip;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Address{" + "street=" + street + ", state=" + state + ", city=" + city + ", zip=" + zip + '}';
    }

}
```

It has simple methods for getting and setting the values of the object...

Now, we can create objects that are "addressable"

```
public class Bank extends Address {
    
}

public class Customer extends Address {
    
}
```

Both the `Bank` and `Customer` inherit from `Address`, meaning that they inherit all the functionality of that class.

Now, lets create some methods which work on `Address`...

```
public void updateAddress(Address address, String street, String city, String state, String zip) {
    address.setStreet(street);
    address.setCity(city);
    address.setState(state);
    address.setZip(zip);
}

public void formatAddress(Address address) {
    System.out.println(address.getStreet());
    System.out.println(address.getCity() + ", " + address.getState() + ", " + address.getZip());
}
```

Pretty basic, one updates the address details and one prints out a formatted form of the `Addreess`...

Now for the magic...

Let's create a `Bank` and `Customer`

```
Bank bank = new Bank();
Customer customer = new Customer();
```

Now, lets update there address details...

```
updateAddress(bank, "Some street", "Some city", "Some state", "Some zip");
updateAddress(customer, "Other street", "Other city", "Other state", "Other zip");
```

And print them...

```
formatAddress(bank);
formatAddress(customer);
```

But wait, how is that possible?!?  Well, that's polymorphism.  Both the `Bank` and `Customer` can be used anywhere that `Address` is expected, because they inherit from this common ancestor class, they have the ability to "behave" like `Address` does.

Now, normally, I'd do all this through interfaces and abstract classes, and I'd probably maintain a `List` of `Address` classes associated with each object, but this is a simple example to help demonstrate a point...

## Issues...

Your setters are around the wrong way, instead of...

```
public void changeStreet(String Street){
    Street = this.Street;
    System.out.println("yo");
}
```

it should be...

```
public void changeStreet(String Street){
    this.Street = Street;
    System.out.println("yo");
}
```

The reason you are having problems with...

```
if (action.equalsIgnoreCase("S")){
    easySave.changeStreet(Street);
} else if (action.equalsIgnoreCase("ST")){
    easySave.changeState(State);
} else if (action.equalsIgnoreCase("C")){
    easySave.changeCity(City);
} else if (action.equalsIgnoreCase("Z")){
    easySave.changeZip(Zip);
}
```

is because `Street`, `State`, `City` and `Zip` are undefined within the context you are trying to use them...

## Editing account...

In order to edit an account, you would need to be able to select one, once you have it selected, you could then manipulate it...

```
        } else if (action.equalsIgnoreCase("E")) {

            Account account = //... Some means by which the user can select the account
            System.out.println("Street(S)\\ State(ST) \\");
            System.out.println("City(C) \\ Zip(Z) \\");

            if (action.equalsIgnoreCase("S")){
                String street = //...
                account.changeStreet(Street);
            } else if (action.equalsIgnoreCase("ST")){
                String State = //...
                account.changeState(State);
            } else if (action.equalsIgnoreCase("C")){
                String City = //...
                account.changeCity(City);
            } else if (action.equalsIgnoreCase("Z")){
                String Zip = //...
                account.changeZip(Zip);        
            }
        }
```

Which probably suggest, you don't really need polymorphism